# Symfony2 how to export the databsase data to csv

Tags: php, symfony, csv, doctrine

I want to export the database data to "CSV"  and download the "CSV" file once I click on a button.

Currently in "controller" I'm fetching all the necessary data from the database, using "repository" for this purpose.

```
$em       = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
$entities = $em->getRepository('SkerpInventoryBundle:InventoryMaster')->findAllIndex();
```

The `$entities` will contain all the data and I want to export that to a "CSV".

In the twig I have a button for download the "CSV" file.

The following is the code of the button in the twig -

```
<a href="{{ path('location') }}">Export as Excel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem??

Code for export:

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

**In the controller:**

```
    $data = array(1,2,3,4);
    $response = new Response($data);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=filename.csv');
    return $response;
```